# Return nested object with recursion - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have an object with nested object:

```
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I need to return all `key: value` of `list` and I must use recursion. I have tried to push the nested object to the local variable in the function, but it fails in the second iteration because the names are different.

Here is the function:

```
function printList(list){
  let nested = {};

  if(list.hasOwnProperty('next')) {
      nested = list.next;
      printList(nested);
  } else {
    return nested;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to solve it with recursion?

It should return the `value` properties. In this case

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Well where in the recursive function are you actually printing anything to the output?

Comment: You should not check whether the object has a `.next` property, you should check whether `nested` is `null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could return an array with the values and get the nested values after a check

```js
function printList({ value, next }) {
    return [value, ...(next ? printList(next) : [])]
}

let list = { value: 1, next: { value: 2, next: { value: 3, next: { value: 4, next: null } } } };

console.log(printList(list));
```

Comment: Here is another one for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395515/js-how-to-get-length-of-multidimensionnel-array#

Answer (score 3):

You can create a function which checks to see if `next` is defined for a given object, if it is, you can add the `value` into an array, along with the rest of the values retrieved from further recursive calls:

```js
const list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};

const get_keys = ({value, next}) => 
 next ? [value, ...get_keys(next)] : [value];
  
console.log(get_keys(list));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that attempts to stay close to your own attempt.

```js
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};

function printList(list){
  if (!list)
    return;

  console.log(list.value)

  if (list.hasOwnProperty('next'))
    printList(list.next);
}

printList(list)
```

Comment: I already find the answer and I like it. But anyway your answer works and it at least deserves an upvote. Thank You very much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
function printList(list) {
  if (list.next) {
    sum = sum + list.value;
    printList(list.next);
  }
  if (!list.next) {
    sum = sum + list.value;
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(printList(list));
```