# How to get length of multidimensionnel array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get length of multidimentionnal array in JS :
This is my array :

```js
const treeData = [
  {
    title: '0-0',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: '0-0-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        children: [
          {
            title: '0-0-0-0',
            key: '0-0-0-0',
          },
          {
            title: '0-0-0-1',
            key: '0-0-0-1',
          },
          {
            title: '0-0-0-2',
            key: '0-0-0-2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        children: [
          {
            title: '0-0-1-0',
            key: '0-0-1-0',
          },
          {
            title: '0-0-1-1',
            key: '0-0-1-1',
          },
          {
            title: '0-0-1-2',
            key: '0-0-1-2',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-2',
        key: '0-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-1',
    key: '0-1',
    children: [
      {
        title: '0-1-0-0',
        key: '0-1-0-0',
      },
      {
        title: '0-1-0-1',
        key: '0-1-0-1',
      },
      {
        title: '0-1-0-2',
        key: '0-1-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-2',
    key: '0-2',
  },
];
```

The output should be : 15
The idea is to map trough all elements and if they have an array child, get the lentgh of it
I'm sure that I will go for a récursive function but it seems to be tricky..
I did'nt found any solutions in internet, have you an idea please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getLengthOfTreeData(treeData) {
    let size = { size: 0 }; // object because it needs to be passed by reference
    return getSize(size, treeData).size;
}

function getSize(size, treeData) { // recursive function
    if (treeData.length === 0) {
        return size;
    }

    size.size += treeData.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < treeData.length; i++) {
        const data = treeData[i];
        if (data.children) getSize(size, data.children);
    }
    return size;
}

console.log(getLengthOfTreeData(treeData));
```